# How to align a row vector and column vector such that the row align to the first entry of the column

Tags: matrices

I have a column vector multiplies by a row vector. I want to align the row vector with the first entry of the column vector.

I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: It is highly appreciated that if you could come up with a minimum example showing where you got stuck. Oh, welcome to TeX.SX.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for simple vectors, but you may need `\vphantom` instead of `\mathstrut` for larger entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document} 
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\begin{bmatrix}d&e&f\end{bmatrix}\\
\mathstrut\\
\mathstrut
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: outer product]

Comment: If you click the check mark, it will remove this question from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2):

For example like this:

```
$$
  \vtop{\kern-\ht\strutbox\hbox{$\pmatrix{a\cr b\cr c}$}} \pmatrix{d & e & f}
$$    
\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's a good idea, but here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{delarray}
\newenvironment{topbmatrix}[1]
  {\begin{array}[t]\lbrack{@{}#1@{}}\rbrack}
  {\end{array}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{topbmatrix}{c} a\\b\\c \end{topbmatrix}
\begin{topbmatrix}{*{3}{c}} d&e&f \end{topbmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]